# What are the finite and co-finite subsets of the set of Natural Numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

Let W be the set of Natural Numbers. What are all of the finite and co-finite subsets of W? It seems that all of the finite subsets of W will be inside of the power set of W, which we know will be uncountably infinite. But what is a co-finite subset of W?

I know that a co-finite subset is a subset whose complement is a finite set but am having trouble extending this definition to this question. For example, is X = {0, 1, 2} a co-finite subset of W?

Comment: A co-finite set would be a set with a finite number of natural numbers *not* in the set. For example, $\{3, 4, 5, 6, \dots\}$ has all natural numbers except $0, 1, 2$.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but just in case, there are are only countably many finite subsets of the natural numbers.

Comment: In the case that {3, 4, 5, 6, ...} is a co-finite (sub)set (of W), what is the difference between it and a finite subset of W? If {3, 4, 5, 6, ...} has all the Natural Numbers but 0, 1, 2, how is it finite, since we would never get to the end of it?

Comment: @nbogs The point is that ${3,4,5,6,...}$ is cofinite but *not* finite.

Comment: @nbogs An example of a set that is neither finite nor cofinite is the set of even numbers, because neither the even numbers nor the odd numbers (the complement of the even numbers) is finite.

Comment: @user76284 This makes much more sense, thanks! By extension, can we say that the set of Natural Numbers is a cofinite set, since it is the complement of at least one finite set, namely of the empty set?

Comment: @nbogs Yes, $\mathbb{N}$ is cofinite in $\mathbb{N}$, because its complement in $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N} - \mathbb{N} = \{\}$ which is finite. I’m not sure what you mean by “complement of *at least* one” though, since the complement of a set (in another set) is always unique.